# GeoHistogram with Graphics

Tags: histograms, geographics

The `GeoHistogram` function appears to use different coordinates to graphics, so that when you overlay they do not have the same origin.

For instance, if I use dataset `Table[{RandomReal[],RandomReal[]},{i,1,100}]`, and plot this as a `GeoHistogram`, then try to `Show` with a set of lines:

```
Graphics@{{Thin, GrayLevel@0.75, Line[{{#/2, #/2}, {#, #}}], 
     Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}}]} & /@ Range[0., 1.0, .1]}
```

Full code:

```
Show[Graphics@{{Thin, GrayLevel@0.75, Line[{{#/2, #/2}, {#, #}}], 
      Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}}]} & /@ Range[0., 1.0, .1]}, 
 Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}}]}], 
 GeoHistogram[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}], GeoBackground -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Automatic]
 ]
```

the two are not compatible for some reason. How can I get these two to have the same coordinate system?

Comment: Can you please upload an image with what you see, and describe what you expect to see? When I evaluate your code, I don't see anything weird (and in fact, I was surprised to see it give output that made sense, because I didn't expect `Graphics` and `GeoGraphics` to play nicely at all!)

Comment: Just for comparison, [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/On4Md.png) is the result of your code on MMA 11.2 in Win78-64. Is it the same for you? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @MarcoB To confirm, I also see this output in 11.3 on OSX.

Comment: I have the same, but my understanding of where the origins are differ; let me add one more thing that might make this clearer

Comment: Hopefully if you plot this triangle a problem occurs

Comment: @MKF I still don't see anything that doesn't make sense. Consider adding something like `Axes->True` to your `Show` to help explain what you're seeing.